# Create a unique username with validation on wordpress registration

Tags: user-registration, wp-register-script, wp-user-query, username

I want to add a unique username on registration and hide this field on the registration form. Its working so far, but its not 100% perfect, because if its 3 times the same number then it will throw a failure.
Does anyone have an idea how i can do this a bit better?

UPDATE::::::

```
function my_add_user_frontend_submitted( $submitted ) {

    // Search for the last ID registered
    $args = array(
    'orderby'      => 'registered', // registered date
    'order'        => 'DESC', // last registered goes first
    'number'       => 1 // limit to the last one, not required
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );
    $last_user = $users[0];
    $prefix = 'u_';
    $username = '1000' + $last_user->ID + 1;

    $submitted['user_login'] = $prefix . $username;
    return $submitted;
}
add_filter( 'um_add_user_frontend_submitted', 'my_add_user_frontend_submitted', 10, 1 );
```

OLD VERSION::::::

```
function generate_unique_username( $username ) {
    $username = rand(10000,100000);

    if ( ! username_exists( $username ) ) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="u_' . $username .'" />';
    } else {
        $new_username = rand(10000,100000);
        if ( ! username_exists( $new_username ) ) {
            echo '<input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="u_' . $new_username .'" />';
        } else {
            echo '<input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" value="u_' . rand(10000,100000) .'" />';
        }
    }
}
add_action('um_after_register_fields', 'generate_unique_username');
```

Comment: Would adding current timestamp to the username be a solution?
Do you need the uername to be a number only?

Comment: it would be a solution, it should only be a number with the u_ prefix... the username is used as a customer number, the best way would be that i get the last registered number and then add +1 but i dont know how i can get the last registered username

Comment: It would be better to do it as you are processing the registration, rather than trying to do it as part of the form. If it's part of the form, what happens if another user loads the form, then before they complete registration, another user loads the form and registers? You'd have a situation where you end up with a non-unique username, it would throw an error to the first user, and they wouldn't know why. If you did it upon form submission, you'd be able to query the db for uniqueness and then process immediately following, allowing for a smoother process.

Comment: thank you butlerblog for this suggestion. can you give me some point where i can start?

Comment: I will completely edit my question now with the new solution, looking forward to feedback.